# Uploading files to Google docs programmatically

Tags: php, python, google-docs

I have many many pdf files around 50GB in my Ebooks folder.
Now i want to upload them in Google docs like Rsync of Linux.
Is it possible to have the script in php or python which uploads all pdf files in Ebooks folder and subfolders to Google docs.

Now the problem is i need to restart computer many times and i want that script should start from where it was left with previous file so that i don't need to manually make selection of files. is it possible

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know where to start or there may be already something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use the [Google Documents API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/) to upload them using a simple HTTP POST with the data. Here's an explanation how to upload and convert documents: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs

The link will provide you will examples and all you need to do what you were asking for.

To be more precise this is what you are looking for if you want to upload pdf's: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ResumableUploadPUT

- [Python Google Documents API guide](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html)
- [PHP Google Documents API guide](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html)